# Send all output from a specific celery task to a file

Tags: python, logging, celery

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

tasks = Celery("tasks")

@tasks.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender: Celery, **kwargs) -> None:
    """Setup periodic tasks."""
    sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(minute="*/15"), my_task.s())

@tasks.task
def my_task()
    SomeModule.do_something()
```

How do I redirect **everything** that my_function outputs to a single specific file? Just using logger won't work, because that module might be using all kind of weird things like print(), different loggers into nested threads and other things that I have no control over. There might also be different tasks running a different function from the same module at the same time.

Ideally it'd be something simple like

```
@tasks.task
@logs_to("path/to/file.txt")
def my_task()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This can be done with logger. specify custom logger (my_task_logger) in logging configuration and get that logger to be used in my_task. make sure to pass args for logging handler here with specific file name (here file.txt) 
e.g 
LOG_MY_TASK = logging.getLogger('my_task_logger')

use LOG_MY_TASK in my_task to log and you should have file.txt created with logs

Comment: That doesn't catch print().

Comment: for the specific to my_task assign print = logger.<log level e.g info>